# Get AWS region names with Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I am developing a Rails application for AWS and would like to create drop down menu for region names, like "us-east-1" etc.

If someone already created gem to get them, I want to use it. Does anyone know such a gem or useful API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Ruby (aws-sdk gem) supports enumerating region names:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(:access_key_id => '...', :secret_access_key => '...')
ec2.regions.map(&:name)
=> ["eu-west-1", "sa-east-1", "us-east-1", "ap-northeast-1", "us-west-2", "us-west-1", "ap-southeast-1"]
```

You can also use a client interface to the DescribeRegions call:

```
ec2.client.describe_regions
=> { :region_info=>[
    {:region_name=>"eu-west-1", :region_endpoint=>"ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"}, 
    {:region_name=>"sa-east-1", :region_endpoint=>"ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com"}, 
    {:region_name=>"us-east-1", :region_endpoint=>"ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"}, 
    {:region_name=>"ap-northeast-1", :region_endpoint=>"ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com"}, 
    {:region_name=>"us-west-2", :region_endpoint=>"ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"}, 
    {:region_name=>"us-west-1", :region_endpoint=>"ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"}, 
    {:region_name=>"ap-southeast-1", :region_endpoint=>"ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"}
  ], 
  :request_id=>"04458cac-bdf2-4847-bf1f-c7ea65813777"
}
```

You can view the gem docs here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html

Answer (score 1):

On mine I can do:

```
>> `ec2-describe-regions`.scan(/REGION\s+(\S+)/).flatten
=> ["eu-west-1", "sa-east-1", "us-east-1", "ap-northeast-1", "us-west-2", "us-west-1", "ap-southeast-1"]
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to find out my goal!

Answer (score 1):

I found the Gem!

http://rubydoc.info/gems/aws/2.5.6/Aws/Ec2:describe_regions