# Getting the list of aws regions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am trying to populate the aws regions in a dropdown and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11661332/5782310) issue as well but I keep getting error like

```
    [AWS EC2 403 1.950727 0 retries] describe_regions() AWS::EC2::Errors::UnauthorizedOperation You are not authorized to perform this operation.

AWS::EC2::Errors::UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

I have the correct access keys but I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Does the key you're using have access to `ec2::DescribeRegions`?

Comment: do i check that by loggin in my account?

Comment: @SushantBajracharya you will need to go into: `IAM > Users > *username*` and attach the necessary policies.

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos, can u turn that into answer plz

Comment: @SushantBajracharya done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error message you are getting all you have to do is make sure that the IAM user that owns the key has access to `ec2:: DescribeRegions`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the policy that needs to be added for you to have access to describe regions for ec2 instance. Create this custom policy in AWS IAM (Root User or a AWS Console Admin Will be able to do that).

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
  "Resource": "*"
}]
}
```